# "Требуется идентификатор" при указании типа обобщенного класса

Tags: c#

Создаю класс:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Bank<int>
{
    int[] clients;

    public Bank() { }

    public Bank(int[] _clients)
    {
        this.clients = _clients;
    }
}
```

В названии класса тип `<int>` подчеркивается красным, текст ошибки:

> Требуется идентификатор. Синтаксическая ошибка требуется ","

При этом в коде всё нормально. Почему? В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 3):

```
class Bank<T>
{
    T[] clients;

    public Bank() { }

    public Bank(T[] _clients)
    {
        this.clients = _clients;
    }
}
```

И создание объекта этого класса:

```
var xz = new Bank<int>();
```

Как по мне, так создание "обобщенного" класса, в котором сразу же объявляется тип, самую малость лишено смысла :)

Если вкратце, то обобщенные классы должны описываться без указания конкретного класса, а уже при создании экземпляра этого класса указывается тип, с которым в данный момент будем работать.

Answer (score 2):

Кроме варианта Rostyslav Kuzmovych можно сделать ещё так:

```
class Bank
{
    int[] clients;

    public Bank() { }

    public Bank(int[] _clients)
    {
        this.clients = _clients;
    }
}
```

Comment: а если поле clients всегда должно иметь тип int[], то этот вариант будет даже получше :)